# Unity3d. How to get screen or world position of ui element

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have UI elements (image, etc). Canvas attached to camera. 
There is a `RectTransform`, but how to convert this data to screen or world coordinates and get center point of this image?

Tried `RectTransform.GetWorldCorners` but it returns zero vectors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`yourRectTransform.rect.center` for the centre point in local space.

`yourRectTransform.TransformPoint` to convert to world space.

It is odd that `RectTransform.GetWorldCorners` doesn't work as stated. Per one of the other answers you need to call after Awake (so layout can occur).

Comment: Thx Huacanacha. Exactly what I need

Comment: I searched so many hours to find `yourRectTransform.TransformPoint(Vector3)`.... Thanks a lot !

Comment: indeed, I can't get `RectTransform.GetWorldCorners` to work at all: below Kay reports it only seems to work if the canvas is world space style.

Answer (score 4):

I found that both GetWorldCorners and TransformPoint only work on Start(), not on Awake(), as if we'll have to wait for the content to be resized

```
    Vector3 min = referenceArea.rectTransform.TransformPoint(referenceArea.rectTransform.rect.min);
    Vector3 max = referenceArea.rectTransform.TransformPoint(referenceArea.rectTransform.rect.max);

    elementToResize.transform.localScale = new Vector3(Mathf.Abs(min.x - max.x) , Mathf.Abs(min.y - max.y), 1f);
    elementToResize.transform.position = referenceArea.rectTransform.TransformPoint(referenceArea.rectTransform.rect.center);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can work with [`GetWorldCorners`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.GetWorldCorners.html) but only when using a child that has real dimensions. I got reasonable values for a child of a world space canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Following Huacanacha's guidance,

```
Vector2 _centerPosition = _rectTransform.TransformPoint(_rectTransform.rect.center);
```

will give you the WorldCoordinate of the center of the image.